# Error while installing Franz on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: apt, software-installation, official-repositories

I am trying to follow [this](http://omgfoss.com/install-franz-linux/) guide to install Franz on Ubuntu 18.04.1.

I have downloaded the .tar.gz package, extracted it and tried to run ./franz - then I got an error about the missing libconf library, so I tried to install it as it says in the guide, but the `liconf-2-4` package is missing from the repositories...

According to [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgconf-2-4), it should be in the Universe Repository, which I have enabled.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct spelling? the package's name is lib**g**conf-2-4 . Did you `sudo apt update` after enabling the universe repository? what is the output of `apt-cache policy libgconf-2-4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install missing library to open Franz.

```
sudo apt install libgconf-2-4
```

Comment: It seems the guide I was following had a typo, that's why I wasn't able to find it in the repos...